# How to calculate a value grouped by one attribute, but provided in the second column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filter, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I have a datarame with Id of orders, Id Client,Date_order and some metrics (not to much important)
I want to get number of last ID order of Client for all rows

I tried this one:

```
data=pd.DataFrame({'ID': [ 133853.0,155755.0,149331.0,337270.0,
  775727.0,200868.0,138453.0,738497.0,666802.0,697070.0,128148.0,1042225.0,
  303441.0,940515.0,143548.0],
 'CLIENT':[ 235632.0,231562.0,235632.0,231562.0,734243.0,
   235632.0,235632.0,734243.0,231562.0,734243.0,235632.0,734243.0,231562.0,
   734243.0,235632.0],
 'DATE_START': [ ('2017-09-01 00:00:00'),
   ('2017-10-05 00:00:00'),('2017-09-26 00:00:00'),
   ('2018-03-23 00:00:00'),('2018-12-21 00:00:00'),
   ('2017-11-23 00:00:00'),('2017-09-08 00:00:00'),
   ('2018-12-12 00:00:00'),('2018-11-21 00:00:00'),
   ('2018-12-01 00:00:00'),('2017-08-22 00:00:00'),
   ('2019-02-06 00:00:00'),('2018-02-20 00:00:00'),
   ('2019-01-20 00:00:00'),('2017-09-17 00:00:00')]})
data.groupby('CLIENT').apply(lambda x:max(x['ID']))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzZJH.png)

It takes into account all the IDs and displays only three rows of Client and max ID, but I need to look only among the previous ones for all rows DataFrame. Help please)

Comment: can you try `data.groupby('CLIENT')['ID'].max()`?

Comment: add a sample data and an expected output to demonstrate the question please. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data['id_last_order']= data.sort_values('DATE_START').groupby('CLIENT')['ID'].transform(lambda x: x.shift())
```

or with creation function

```
def select_last_order_id(row):
    df = data[(data['CLIENT']==row['CLIENT'])&(data['DATE_START']<row['DATE_START'])]
    try:
        value = df.groupby(by=['ID','CLIENT'],as_index=False,sort = False).agg('max')['ID'].values[0]
    except Exception:
        value = None
    return(value)

data['id_last_order'] = data.apply(select_last_order_id,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data=pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [133853.0,155755.0,149331.0,337270.0,
           775727.0,200868.0,138453.0,738497.0,
           666802.0,697070.0,128148.0,1042225.0,
           303441.0,940515.0,143548.0],
    'CLIENT':[235632.0,231562.0,235632.0,231562.0,734243.0,
              235632.0,235632.0,734243.0,231562.0,734243.0,
              235632.0,734243.0,231562.0,734243.0,235632.0],
    'DATE_START': [('2017-09-01 00:00:00'), ('2017-10-05 00:00:00'),
                   ('2017-09-26 00:00:00'), ('2018-03-23 00:00:00'),
                   ('2018-12-21 00:00:00'), ('2017-11-23 00:00:00'),
                   ('2017-09-08 00:00:00'), ('2018-12-12 00:00:00'),
                   ('2018-11-21 00:00:00'), ('2018-12-01 00:00:00'),
                   ('2017-08-22 00:00:00'), ('2019-02-06 00:00:00'),
                   ('2018-02-20 00:00:00'), ('2019-01-20 00:00:00'),
                   ('2017-09-17 00:00:00')]
})

data.groupby('CLIENT').apply(lambda df:
    df[df['DATE_START'] == df['DATE_START'].max()].iloc[0][['ID', 'DATE_START']]
)
```

Output:

```
CLIENT            ID             DATE_START
231562.0    666802.0    2018-11-21 00:00:00
235632.0    200868.0    2017-11-23 00:00:00
734243.0   1042225.0    2019-02-06 00:00:00
```

Let's break this down:

1.) Group By `CLIENT`. this will form an iterable of dataframes, grouped by `CLIENT`.

2.) apply a function to each dataframe in the group with a logic (that's what the `apply(lambda df: ...)` part is for)

3.) for each dataframe, find the most recent `DATE_START`, and then subset each dataframe to show only `ID` with the latest `DATE_START` (that's what the `df[df['DATE_START'] == df['DATE_START'].max()]` is for).

4.) At this point, I don't know what logic you want to apply if there are multiple orders from a client on the same date. In this case, I used the first match (`.iloc[0]`).

5.) And then I return the `ID` and the `DATE_START`.
6.) `pandas` will then understand that you want the logic you applied to each dataframe in the iterable to be combined row-wise, which is why the output is such.

Let me know if this is what you're looking for.q

Comment: It's the same what i do in question)))) I need Dataframe with such amount of rows, but need to add column with last order ID before current

Comment: you need to know how many rows in a group (`CLIENT`) have the max `ID`?

Comment: not quite)I need ID of last order regarding the current order by CLIENT for all rows